# Do I have an DOM-based XSS attack?

Tags: xss

I can't show code right now, but I don't think it matters. 
In one area of my very dynamic and scripted site, I had a group of links to an external site. I noticed that a lot of text in a section that follows was underlined, and on investigation in DevTools I saw that the last link in that group was missing a closing anchor tag. Fixed that, fine. But on next reload, ***it comes back***. So...I ripped out those links, ripped out the whole section. Those changes **do** show up so the page is not cached. But those links with missing closing tag.... ***comes back***. When I look at the code in Google Dev Tools, I see code that is NOT in the file, just as though it were cached. But the file is not being cached, it is updated on the server, and I can see the other changes I've made (both IE and Google). The console shows tons of crap from Google, advertising, FB, etc. I tried ripping out the You Tube, the Facebook, etc. and even with those elements missing, even without my JS, it  ***comes back***.

So...I can only think of some kind of XSS attack. I've never seen this before. Any ideas?

Comment: Impossible to say. Doesn't make much sense if it is, since it doesn't really "attack" you, just annoy. As with any debugging, making small, incremental changes until you find what causes it is the best path forward.

Comment: A lot of things are happening that are annoying. I hope this is not the Russians. Thank you...I've never heard of only the bad part of something being cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I built this site last year under time pressure, it had a lot of includes, many "Russian nesting dolls". Aware of that, and wanting to try to limit that depth and save time, in some cases I copy-pasted common content, although I knew better. This included a set of links, and the last link was missing a closing "< /a>". This got copied to two other places. So when I fixed the error in the index file on Friday, the problem still existed in two other places, which I finally hunted down this morning. SOLVED. [Had I continued the original structure pattern with two more includes, I could have found and solved the issue once. But I also need to document my structure on paper, because everything that was in my head last year during the build is this year....um,much less familiar. Let this be a warning to you, son.]

Jeez.

Comment: Oh, and just for clarity...this means there was no XSS attack.